# Hibernate Validate Object inside ConstraintValidator with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I create one field-level-constraint just like this example https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e281 and put then in my field that is an object

```
public classe Car {

  @validateEngine
 private Engine engine;
 ...
}
```

my Engine class:

```
public class Engine {
   @ValidadeEngineName
   private String name;
   @NotNull
   private Integer size;
}
```

It`s possible to in my validateEngineImpl

```
 public class validateEngineImpl implements ConstraintValidator<validateEngine, String> {



        @Override
        public void initialize(validateEngine constraintAnnotation) {
            System.out.println("s");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Engine value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
            if(value == null){
    return true;
    }else{
       //HERE I NEED TO execute one validation in engine, 
but I want to use the annotations, something like 
Validator.valide(value), or I need to validate one by one? Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value.getName())....
        }
    }
```

Using the code from @Hervian, works but in my validateEngineNameImpl I lost the @Autowired

```
public class validateEngineNameImpl implements ConstraintValidator<validateEngineName, String> {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(validateEngine constraintAnnotation) {
        System.out.println("s");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Engine value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
       //Here my myService are not autowired
    }

}
```

It`s possible don`t lost the @Autowired, or pass somethig to my validateEngineNameImpl from validateEngineImpl?

Answer (score 1):

In your Car class, simply annotate the Engine field with @Valid.

Then, calling:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> set = validator.validate(car);
```

will "go into" the engine instance and validate the various annotated fields against their ConstraintValidators.

Try it out - set the size attribute to null fx. You should get a non-empty set of ConstraintViolations.

Comment: It almost worked, in my Engine I have another custom constrain, that I need to get some Autowired service with spring-boot, so if I call with this code, my service are not autowired, I update my question with this another code.. tks

Comment: and other thing when i Run Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> set = validator.validate(car); don`t return to my view the message from car validation, only the message from my firs customcontraint